# Monte Carlo simulation in Python: How to get exactly identical transition probabilities from modeled data?

Tags: python, arrays, database, for-loop, random

I have run this simulation (given below) and got the simulated transition probabilities for dry-to-dry and wet-to-wet conditions. The simulated results for dry-to-dry are almost equal to the estimated dry-to-dry (d2d_tran). But, the simulated wet-to-wet values are substantially lower than the estimated ones. It seems there is something wrong in the program. I tried several other ways but haven’t got the expected results. Can you please run the program and suggest me how I may get improved results for wet-to-wet probabilities? Thanks in advance.

My codes:

```
import numpy as np
import random, datetime

d2d = np.zeros(12)
d2w = np.zeros(12)
w2w = np.zeros(12)
w2d = np.zeros(12)
pd2d = np.zeros(12)
pw2w = np.zeros(12)

dry = [0.333] ##unconditional probability of dry for January
d2d_tran = [0.564,0.503,0.582,0.621,0.634,0.679,0.738,0.667,0.604,0.564,0.577,0.621]
w2w_tran = [0.784,0.807,0.8,0.732,0.727,0.728,0.64,0.64,0.665,0.717,0.741,0.769]
mu = [3.71,4.46,4.11,2.94,3.01,2.87,2.31,2.44,2.56,3.45,4.32,4.12]
sigma = [6.72,7.92,7.49,6.57,6.09,5.53,4.38,4.69,4.31,5.71,7.64,7.54]

days = np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
rain = np.array([])

for y in xrange(0,10000):
    for m in xrange(0,12):
    #Include leap years in the calculation and creat random variables for each month
        if ((y%4 == 0 and y%100 != 0) or y%400 == 0) and m==1: 
            random_num = np.random.rand(29)
        else:
            random_num = np.random.rand(days[m])

    #lets generate a rainfall amount for first day of the random series
        if random_num[0] <= dry[0]:
            random_num[0] = 0
        else:
            random_num[0] = abs(random.gauss(mu[0],sigma[0]))

# generate the whole series in sequence of month and year
        for i in xrange(0,days[m]):
            if random_num[i-1] == 0: #if yesterday was dry
                if random_num[i] <= d2d_tran[m]: #check today against the dry2dry transition probabilities
                    random_num[i] = 0
                    d2d[m] += 1.0
                else:
                    random_num[i] = abs(random.gauss(mu[m],sigma[m]))
                    d2w[m] += 1.0

            else:
                if random_num[i] <= w2w_tran[m]:
                    random_num[i] = abs(random.gauss(mu[m],sigma[m]))
                    w2w[m] += 1.0                         
                else:
                    random_num[i] = 0
                    w2d[m] += 1.0



        pd2d[m] = d2d[m]/(d2d[m] + d2w[m])
        pw2w[m] = w2w[m]/(w2d[m] + w2w[m])


print 'Simulated transition probability of dry2dry:\n', np.around(pd2d, decimals=3)
print 'Simulated transition probability of wet2wet:\n', np.around(pw2w, decimals=3)

### pd2d and pw2w of generated data should be identical to d2d_tran and w2w_tran respectively
```

Comment: Please don't delete all of the code content from your question. It makes it difficult to understand what the answer refers to, and renders it useless to anyone who's searching for a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulation looks correct as far as it goes, and after running it for 8000 years, I get transition probabilities within .001 most of the time, and there is convergence as the number of days increases.

Nothing guarantees that you will get the exact transition probabilities - on any single run you may get anything. What you've done is generate an estimator for each single transition probability that has mean equal to the actual value (0.345), and some positive variance. The variance of your estimator decreases with n = sample size, but it will always be positive.

If you'd like values closer to the actual transition probabilities (faster convergence), apply some well-known variance reduction techniques: [Stratified Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling), [Importance Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling), etc. - too many to mention. Here's a quick technique - take the uniform random deviates generated by np.random.rand(), and estimate as usual. Then generate another estimator using the transformed deviates: `[(1-x) for x in stored_deviates]`. The average of the two estimators has reduced variance (by .5).